# How to solve $k_b \bar b - k_a \bar a + \frac{1}{t} \cdot k_a \bar a - \frac{1}{t}(\bar c - \bar a_1) = \bar a_1 - \bar b_1$

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I need to solve $k_b$, $k_a$ and $t$ in this equation in a program I'm creating:
$$k_b \bar b - k_a \bar a + \frac{1}{t} \cdot k_a \bar a - \frac{1}{t}(\bar c - \bar a_1) = \bar a_1 - \bar b_1$$
All the vectors are known (they are 3D vectors). I was planning to make a system of equations where I'd split this equation in three by the x, y and z components of the vectors, and then use Gaussian elimination to solve it. But as I understand it, that would need each term on the left side to be of the form $variable \cdot coefficient$, so that I could make a matrix of the coefficients. But I don't know what to do with the third term where $\frac{1}{t}$ is multiplied by $k_a$.

Is there some way to get this equation to a simpler form? Is it possible to use Gaussian elimination for a system of equations like this? Is there another algorithmic way to solve these equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to calculate $t$ when $\vec a$ is not parallel to $\vec b$

Define $\vec d \equiv \vec c - \vec a_1$ and $\vec e \equiv \vec a_1 - \vec b_1$ and $\vec f\equiv \vec a \times \vec b$

multiply through by $t$ to get ..
$$tk_b \vec b + (1-t)k_a \vec a = \vec d + t\vec e  \tag{1}$$
taking the dot product with $\vec f$ we have ...
$$ 0 = \vec d \cdot \vec f+t(\vec e \cdot \vec f)$$
So that 
$$ t =- \frac{\vec d \cdot \vec f}{\vec e \cdot \vec f}$$
note that no solution exists if $(\vec d \cdot \vec f)=0$ or $(\vec e \cdot \vec f) =0$

If $\vec f=0$ then solutions only exist if $(\vec d \times \vec b)\times (\vec e \times \vec b)=0$ and $(\vec d \times \vec a)\times (\vec e \times \vec a)=0$.

Comment: Did you forget to multiply the $k_b \vec b$ term by t?

Comment: Also I don't really understand why the left hand side goes to zero when you take the dot product with $\vec f$. How does that work?

Comment: Yes I did forget to multiply by t, but that doesn't change what I was trying to show you. I did edit it back in.

Comment: The LHS goes to zero because $\vec a \times \vec b$ is perpendicular to both $\vec a $ and $\vec b$